Trouble decoding JWT token generated in Next.js and decoded in .NET Core
I'm encountering an issue when attempting to decode a JWT token generated in Next.js and decoded in .NET Core. The error message I receive is

Token decoding failed: IDX10517: Signature validation failed. The token's kid is missing. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey, KeyId: '', InternalId: 'TNZnnX06UUsp0wgkdNlMB79dZ0uLVMBsLK4oOHDwARg'. , KeyId: '. Number of keys in TokenValidationParameters: '1'.
Number of keys in Configuration: '0'.
Exceptions caught:
'[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
token: '[PII of type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. See https://aka.ms/IDX10503 for details.

In Next.js (frontend), I'm generating the token using:
const secret_key = process.env.SECRET_KEY || "";
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const generateAccessToken = (payload: any) => {
    try {
        const options = { expiresIn: '1h' };
        // Sign the token
        return jwt.sign(payload, secret_key, options);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error generating access token:", error);
        return null;
    }
};

const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
        const payload = {
            username: username,
            password: password
        };

        const token = generateAccessToken(payload); // Generate token
        console.log(token);

        const res = await axios.get(`User/login?un=${username}&pw=${password}&t=${token}`);
        console.log(res.data); // Assuming you want to log the response data
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
};

In .NET Core (backend), I'm attempting to decode the token using:
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using cp_loan.Data;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace cp_loan.Services
{
    public class TokenGenerator
    {
        private readonly JwtOptions _jwtOptions;
        private readonly SymmetricSecurityKey _key;

        public TokenGenerator(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _jwtOptions = configuration.GetSection("JWTOptions").Get<JwtOptions>()
                ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("JWTOptions section is missing or invalid.");

            var signingKey = configuration["JWTOptions:SigningKey"]
                             ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("JWT signing key is missing.");

            _key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signingKey));
        }

        public ClaimsPrincipal DecodeToken(string jwtToken)
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            try
            {
                var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = _key,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = _jwtOptions.Issuer,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = _jwtOptions.Audience,
                    ValidateLifetime = true
                };

                return tokenHandler.ValidateToken(jwtToken, tokenValidationParameters, out _);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Token decoding failed: {ex.Message}");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}

Error Description:
The error message suggests that the token's 'kid' (Key ID) is missing, resulting in signature validation failure. It appears that the token validation process is unable to locate the necessary key for validation.
How can I resolve this issue?
